# AJAX not working with myfaces 2.1 and rich faces 4.3

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, myfaces

We are upgrading from jsf 1.2 to jsf 2. 
We are using apache myfaces 2.1 and rich faces 4.3.

The issue is , it seems that `<a4j:commandButton>` tag AJAX feature is broken.
Below is the xhtml file.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">


    <h:form prependId="false" id="questionsForm">   

        <!-- other form fields are not shown -->
        <a4j:commandButton  id="questions" value="Clear" action="#{bean.clearAction}"/> 
    </h:form>

</html>
```

When the "clear" button is clicked , back end code executes but an entire page reload happens (page refreshes again).
Pre-migration code works perfectly fine with no page reload.

Can anyone please help in how to get this AJAX work in rich faces  tags ?

Answer (score 2):

As given attributes you have to tell `a4j:commandButton`,

- which parts you want to have executed (e.g. which input fields of the current page shall be updated)
- which parts of the page you want to have re-rendered

The first is done with the attribute `execute`, the last is done with the attribute `render`. If none of both is given, the button behaves like a traditional `h:commandButton` (which explains the described behaviour)

**Update**: Also check that the `<head>` and `<body>` tag have to be like `<h:head>` and `<h:body>` so JSF has a chance to add mandatory javascript- and css libraries.

**Update**: Have you double-checked your action returns void/""/`null` and not any forwards? (see also ["a4j:commandButton makes a full page reload RichFaces 3.3.3 CR1"](https://community.jboss.org/message/529859#529859))

Comment: @lray:Thanks for your reply.I tried giving execute and render attribute values , but no change in behaviour.Page reload still happens.

Comment: @lray:I also tried adding h:head and h:body , but same issue exists

Comment: @Atul Just tested it locally, but with Mojarra Faces 2.1.7 and a richfaces 4.3.3 Final. Even without render/execute no fresh reload takes place. So it has to be a problem outside the given xhtml - code.

Comment: @lray:Thanks,yes I checked earlier that my method returns void , also tried returning null from it , but no success.I agree that it has to be a outside xhtml issue. Will post the reason once some resolution is found

Comment: Okay. Well, good luck ... and yeah, an upvote would be appreciated. :-)